# Run JavaScript inside <script src="..."></script> Tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I've a JavaScript file that processes tab switches. Here is the source:

```
var tCount = 0;

function SwitchToTab(id) {
    if (id < 0 || id > tCount) { id = 0; }

    for (var i = 0; i < tCount; i++) { document.getElementById("tab" + i).className = ""; }
    document.getElementById("tab" + id).className = "active";

    for (var i = 0; i < tCount; i++) { document.getElementById("area" + i).style.display = "none"; }
    document.getElementById("area" + id).style.display = "";
}

function InitializeTabs(initialTabId, tabsCount) {
    tCount = tabsCount;
    SwitchToTab(initialTabId);
}
```

I'm trying to make it as short as possible like this:

```
<script src="Resources/Tabs.js">InitializeTabs(0, 4);</script>
```

It doesn't works but it works if I separate them like this:

```
<script src="Resources/Tabs.js"></script>
<script>InitializeTabs(0, 4);</script>
```

So, is there any way to run JavaScript inside `<script src="..."></script>` tags? What I am missing?

Comment: no. you will need to have a separate script tag.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. A `<script>` has **either** a `src` or content, not both.

Comment: call InitializeTabs right after you defined it.

Comment: I was not the downvoter but likely its because you could have find this out yourself with a simple google search.  There is a trend to downvote questions that can be trivially answered with obvious searches.

Comment: I already found the solution (_seperate script tags_) but I just wonder why that works. However, I'm surprised!

Comment: I didn't downvote - but why dollar signs on every variable?  You only need to do that with PHP; you're making a lot of unnecessary globals this way.

Comment: @ScottKaye Oh... I'm coming from PHP, good point! :)

Comment: What about self calling functions in tabs.js ?

Comment: @FoxitcL What about a good example? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The html spec dictates that a `<script>` tag does one or the other.

[`<script>`Tag Html Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html), emphasis mine.

> The script may be defined within the contents of the SCRIPT element or in an external file. If the src attribute is not set, user agents must interpret the contents of the element as the script. **If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI.**

Comment: If you talk about the HTML spec you should link to the spec, not to W3schools which is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

You are suppose to do it the second way. in `<script src="Resources/Tabs.js">InitializeTabs(0, 4);</script>` you are referencing an external javascript file, your inline code should go into a second script block.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `src`, or put JavaScript inside the tag.

But not both at once. There's no downside to using two tags anyway (apart from larger file size).

Answer (score 0):

When you include `<script src="Resources/Tabs.js"></script>`, you are mentioning that you want to use the Javascript which is included inside the `Tabs.js` file so that the compiler knows where to look for `InitializeTabs` function, when it is trying to execute the function.

Now if you want to include some Javascript inline, that is inside the HTML, hen you use the `<script>... JAVASCRIPT HERE .... </script>`

You need to do it like this

```
<script src="Resources/Tabs.js"></script>
<script>InitializeTabs(0, 4);</script>
```

Comment: HTML is interpreted, not compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put javascript inside of `<script src="...` tags, but you could run a JavaScript file which parses the HTML, looking for `<script src` tags, which converts it into two tags.

For example,

```
<script src="Resources/Tabs.js">InitializeTabs(0, 4);</script>
```

would have to be converted into

```
<script src="Resources/Tabs.js"></script>
<script>InitializeTabs(0, 4);</script>
```

Here's the code I tried:

```js
var tags = document.querySelectorAll("script[src]");
[].forEach.call(tags, function(elem){
  var text = elem.innerText;
  var src  = elem.src;
  var parent = elem.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(elem);
  var newTag = document.createElement('script');
  newTag.setAttribute('src', src);
  parent.appendChild(newTag);
  var newTag = document.createElement('script');
  var t = document.createTextNode(text);
  newTag.appendChild(t);
  parent.appendChild(newTag);
});
```

[in a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gv2uwy49/)