# ButtonField confirmation click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to show a confirmation box before shoot the action.

Theres my code in aspx file:

the javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
        $(".alterarStatus").click(function () {
            return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status?');
        });
      </script>
```

The buttonField:

```
  <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField ControlStyle-CssClass="alterarStatus" Text="Status" CommandName="atender" ButtonType="Button"/>
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

But the confirmation box never appears

Theres the generated HTML

http://pastebin.com/1vwReChK

EDIT:

the function which is shooting and doesn't appear the alert before

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string commandname = e.CommandName;

            if (commandname.Equals("atender"))
            {
//I want to show an alert before execute this action
         }
}
```

Comment: Can you post generated HTML?

Comment: @dfsq Yes, I can...please, see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a `<script>` tag with both a `src` and content, create two script tags and it should work. Also try wrapping it in a `document ready`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {  //equivalient of $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".alterarStatus").click(function () {
            return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status?');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29414108/526704

I think the `ButtonField` is creating buttons with `runat="server"`, so it's posting back when you press them. Try creating it as a `TemplateField` with an `<input type="button" class="alterarStatus" >` instead.

You can see in your generated html that you're getting inputs with `onclick=__doPostBack()`s which is stopping the javascript from firing because it's posting back.

> `<input type="button" value="Status" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;atender$4&#39;)" class="alterarStatus" />`

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <input type="button" class="alterarStatus" value="Alterar Status" />
   </ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I edited my question with more details about the function which I need to confirm before...

Comment: Sorry, it works...I didn' see that is in on ready function. The alert appears but the cancel button doesn' cancel the action

Comment: I did mark as read and I will create another question with this 'detail'

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is that, you are calling your `javascript` code and
`plugin` in one script which is wrong.

It should be something like this:-

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { 
        $(".alterarStatus").click(function () {
            alert('Tem certeza que deseja alterar o status?');
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<columns>
            <asp:ButtonField ControlStyle-CssClass="alterarStatus" Text="Status" CommandName="atender" ButtonType="Button"/>
      </columns>
</GridView>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Please, see my edit with more details about the question. I have tried it but the alert never appears

Comment: It works...as the @DleH answer. The alert shows but the cancel button doesn't cancel the action