# Changing the value of paragraph using external js file code

Tags: javascript, external

I have created an html file

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="demo">l</p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="profile/test.js">
    s(shiva);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

i want to change the value of the paragaraph. So my external js file is

```js
function s(nam) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = nam;
}
```

But is not changing can anyone suggest me how can change the value.

Comment: Related: [Run JavaScript inside <script src=“…”></script> Tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414053/run-javascript-inside-script-src-script-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not include code in a javascript tag with a "src" attribute. So move the loose javascript in a new tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="profile/test.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    s('shiva');
</script>
```

Comment: I changed but the paragraph value haven't changed

Comment: You need to put text inside quotes '' or "" like 'shiva' or "shiva". Do you have your inspection tool from your browser open? That would tell you about errors like "Uncaught ReferenceError: shiva is not defined"