# How can you execute a function to modify the CSS code once a button is clicked in HTML and Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, button

I am attempting to run a function in Javascript when a button is pressed.
The function should modify the CSS code for the background, or "#sperpy", once clicked, but it is not running the function.
I am using Jquery to run a `.click()` function for the id of the button, or "#bg".
I am running this using the latest version of Visual Studio Code.

Here is my full HTML/JS code, along with my CSS code just in case:

**HTML:**

```
    <head>
        <title>run</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="what.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sperpy"> **<!-- this is the background-->**
            <h1>helo</h1>
            <h2>i am [real name]</h2>
            <h2>i am 100 meters from your location and rapidly approaching</h2>
            <h3>I am [age]</h3>
            <h3>I like to play video games and hang out with my friends</h3>
            <h4>said games include minecraft java, brawlhalla, geometry dash, roblox, and muck</h4>
            <h3>I am in the school band and I play saxophone</h3>
            <h3>My favorite color is sea green (the color of the background)</h3>
            <button id="bg">click this button to make it not sea green</button> **<!-- this is the button -->**
            <div id="hello">
                <h6>do not open this div in Inspect Element</h6>
                <!-- this one, with the id of "you-fool" -->
                <div id="you-fool">
                    <!-- there is a trollface here with the caption "problem?". -->
                    <h1 id="fake">great job now you can't see anything</h1> <!-- this is supposed to be shown once the background color changes -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <img id='ron' src="ron.png" width="610px" height="343px">
        </div>
    </body>
```

**JS:**

```
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
        var count = 0;
        function the(){
            count++;
        }
        function up(){
            var a = setInterval(the, 1);
            console.log(a);
        }
        $('#bg').click(function(){ <!-- this is the function I am trying to run, these four lines right here -->
                $('#sperpy').css("background-color: #000000")
            }
        )
        
    </script>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
    margin-left: 10%;
    background-color: #00ffbe;
    text-align: center;
}
#bg{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 5px;
    background-color: #00f;
    border-color: rgb(65,65,255);
}
#bg:hover{
    background-color: rgb(0,0,190);
}
#fake{
    color: #00ffbe;
}
```

Comment: Please see the syntax for jQuery's [css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css2): `.css(propertyName,value )`, i.e. `.css("background-color","#000000")`. Also see [Run JavaScript inside <script src=“…”></script> Tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414053/run-javascript-inside-script-src-script-tags).

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot, now I just need to fix the div tag so it covers everything

Comment: You could change the `background-color` for the `body`, where it is originally declared as `background-color: #00ffbe`, instead of `#sperpy`. But I'm not sure whether that will work in your context.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple fix just do this:

```
      $("button").click(() => $("#sperpy").css("background-color","#000000"))
```

you made mistake with the .css() method.