# Multiple scripts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a trouble regarding in js scripts, I am still learning js and currently trying to do a multi script in one html but I am not getting the decent output. I tried changing the swiper into -1 and -2 for the other but nothing happens. Thanks in advance.

```css
/*Image Slider css*/
.slidecontainer {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: ghostwhite;
}
.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
}
.swiper-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}
.swiper .swiper-button-next,.swiper .swiper-button-prev{
    color: #1C3879;
}
.swiper .swiper-button-next:hover,.swiper .swiper-button-prev:hover{
    color: #fff;
}
.swiper .swiper-pagination-bullet-active{
    background: #fff;
}

/*New arrivals css*/

.newarrivalscontainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #b8ae98;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }
    .swiper{
    width: 80%;
    height: fit-content;
    }
    .swiper-slide img{
    width: 100%;
    }
    .swiper .swiper-button-prev-1,­ .swiper .swiper-button-next-1{
    color: #1C3879;
    }
    .swiper .swiper-pagination-1-b­ullet-active{
    background: #1C3879;
    }
```

Meanwhile this is my html codes for both image slider 1 div and image slider 2 div (with swiperjs)

```html
<!--Image Slider start-->
    <div class="slidecontainer">
         <!-- Slider main container -->
     <div class="swiper-1">
        <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
       <div class="swiper-wrapper">
         <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="slideshow/slidesimg.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="slideshow/slidesimg.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="slideshow/slidesimg.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="slideshow/slidesimg.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="slideshow/slidesimg.png" alt=""></div>
       </div>
         <!-- If we need pagination -->
         <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  
           <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
           <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
           <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  
      </div>
      </div>

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js">

          const swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper-1', {
        autoplay: {
          delay: 4000,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
        loop: true,
      
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },
      
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
      });
      </script>
<!--Image Slider end-->

<!--New Arrivals start--->
<div class="newarrivalscontainer">
  <div class="swiper-2">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrappe­r">
  <!-- Slides -->
  <div class="swiper-slide"­><img src="images/­newarrival1.jpg"></­div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"­><img src="images/­newarrival2.jpg"></­div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"­><img src="images/­newarrival3.jpg"></­div>
  
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagina­tion-1"></div>
  
  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button­-prev-1"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button­-next-1"></div>
  
  </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper-2', {
    autoplay: {
    delay: 3000,
    disableOnInteraction­: false,
    },
    loop: true,
    
    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination-1'­,
    clickable: true,
    },
    
    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next-1­',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev-1­',
    },
    
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: any smart developer will move scripts to external files and bind them inside the head element or by using modules!

Comment: Agreed, be sure to separate your scripts into separate files and minimize your usage of embedded javascript. Be sure to properly add your defer tags where needed!

Comment: okay i'll try doing external js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run JavaScript inside <script src="..."></script> Tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414053/run-javascript-inside-script-src-script-tags)

Comment: There are 2 things to ensure that a script is run after the DOM Content is finished loading. Either by using the `defer` attribute on the script tag or by using an `eventListener` inside the script. The defer attribute has the advantage of not needing an `eventListner` and as such make all variables easily globally accessible. The `eventListener` has the advantage of asynchronous loading. It will load the script at the same time as the other files which can lower the effective loading time if you good at asynchronous scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Any code inside of a script tag with the **src attribute** is entirely **ignored** (unless the src cannot be loaded, in which case the code inside the script tag acts as a fallback). This means you'll need to create a **new** `script` tag underneath with your javascript code, looking something like this.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>

          const swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper-1', {
        autoplay: {
          delay: 4000,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
        loop: true,
      
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },
      
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
      });
</script>
```

Comment: it is not entirely ignored, it is used as fallback

Comment: do i need to do an external js?

Comment: Sorry yes tacoshy is right, it's a fallback but after navigating to your SRC its practically just ignored code. You should do external js code and make sure that it loads AFTER your library code.

Comment: Of course, the question of what happens with code inside of `script` elements with `src` attributes has been asked and answered several times on this site; we don't need more answers to the same question.